# How to get width/height of a div set to 100% in HTML

Tags: html, width

Is there a way to get the width/height of a div that has been set to 100%?

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:
http://jsfiddle.net/TUMsN/1/

When I click on the blue box, the width/height of the parent returns an empty string...

Answer (score 1):

Use `offsetHeight` instead of `style.height`.
You can't use `style.height` because the height of the element isn't given in an inline style attribute, like here:

```
<div style="height: 200px; ">Hello</div>
```

But if you use `offsetHeight` it will work no matter where the height has been set.

http://jsfiddle.net/marcosfromero/TUMsN/2/

Alternatively you can use jQuery and use the `height()` method:

http://jsfiddle.net/marcosfromero/TUMsN/3/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use offsetHeight and offsetWidth.

I have updated the fiddle, have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/TUMsN/4/